# Laravel/Searchbar : how to search around several words

Tags: laravel, searchbar

I try to make a searchbar where you can request several words :
For example, input is "word#1" and "word#2".
I would like the returned results to be rendered with either of the entered words.
Currently, I have this function in my controller but which prohibits a search on several independent words, I have tried several solutions but they do not work.

```
public function search()
    {
        $data = [
            'title'=> $description = 'Recherche sur '.config('app.name'),
            'description'=> $description,
            'heading'=> config('app.name'),
        ];
        
        $q = request()->input('q');

        $products = Product::where('title','like',"%$q%")
                    ->orWhere('subtitle','like',"%$q%")
                    ->orWhere('description','like',"%$q%")
                    ->paginate();
        
        return view('products.search', $data)->with('products', $products);
    }
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: So in your example, the value of `$q` is `word#1 word#2`? Can you clarify what kind of output do you want to achieve? What if I input "dog cat"

Comment: If I input `"dog cat"`, you want all results with either `"dog"` or `"cat"` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to search with all the words entered input, in your code you must loop it word per word. e.g.

```
    $q = request()->input('q');
    $words = explode(' ', $q);

    $query = Product::query();

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $query->orWhere('title','like',"%$word%")
            ->orWhere('subtitle','like',"%$word%")
            ->orWhere('description','like',"%$word%");
    }

    $products = $query->paginate();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which was very appropriate.
However, I would still like to improve my research but I can't do it. 
Can I ask you to please go to this topic? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716460/laravel-searchbar-how-to-be-more-relevant-in-a-multi-keywords-search
You would help me a lot.