# Laravel/Searchbar : how to be more relevant in a multi keywords search?

Tags: laravel, searchbar

Here is my code, it allows you to do a keyword search and it works well when searching on several "OR" words. However, I want to make the results more relevant.
I would like the results to be sorted by the number of searched words they have.
For example :
The two words entered in a search are "blue" and "red". Well, I would like the records that contain "blue" AND "red" to be the first to be sorted.
Here is my current code:

```
public function search()
{
    $data = [
        'title'=> $description = 'Recherche sur '.config('app.name'),
        'description'=> $description,
        'heading'=> config('app.name'),
    ];
    
    $q = request()->input('q');

    $words = explode(' ', $q);

    $query = Product::query();

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $query->orWhere('title','like',"%$word%")
            ->orWhere('subtitle','like',"%$word%")
            ->orWhere('description','like',"%$word%");
    }
    
    $products = $query->paginate();
    
    return view('products.search', $data)->with('products', $products);
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here may help you: [How to get and order the most relevant entries from the database with multiple keywords Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657297/how-to-get-and-order-the-most-relevant-entries-from-the-database-with-multiple-k)

But the answer there is not "perfect", because its only sorting per 25 records its not using the whole table.

You can use [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout), but you have some setting up to do. I suggest you start experimenting using **Algolia** or **MeiliSearch** driver here because those drivers have excellent smart searching.

**Algolia**
This is NOT FREE, but there's a FREE TIER here if you exceed you will have to pay https://www.algolia.com/pricing/

**Meilisearch**
This is Open source, you can install this on your own server.